# What is the Masterwork property on a Wooden Stake for?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

A [Vampire Slayer's Kit](https://aonprd.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Vampire%20slayer%27s%20kit) contains four Masterwork [Wooden Stakes](https://aonprd.com/EquipmentWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Wooden%20stake). They are listed as a very weak weapon, just a bit weaker than a dagger. Being Masterwork helps to hit with them just slightly more often, but that's it.

They cannot be used to impale a [vampire](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterTemplates.aspx?ItemName=Vampire) until the creature is already helpless, unless [Called Shots](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/called-shots/) are allowed, and even then, a critical hit must be scored. I would not attempt a tactic whose chance of success is less than 5% (because a critical hit also needs to be confirmed). Well, this would work for somebody who can reliably deal 50 points of damage with a wooden stake, but this would be a weird situation, especially given that the stake is a light weapon: you only add half your STR bonus to strikes.

I then thought that it could work as a [Masterwork Tool](https://aonprd.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Masterwork%20tool) for slaying a helpless vampire, but this is not World of Darkness, and no check is required.

Now, this seemingly worthless item costs 300 gp because it is Masterwork. You get it for "free" with the kit, but I might just be missing something.

It could be used in breaking the game via buying the kit for 500 gp and then selling the stakes for 600 gp, but Golarion's economy is weak enough and doesn't need another punch.

**Is a *Masterwork Wooden Stake* actually worth anything other than fluff**?

Comment: I've searched for it, couldn't find anything but fluff as reasons. But I don't feel it'd be right to give that as answer this early in the question's lifetime. There's probably plenty materials out there I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 6):

### Mechanical benefits of the masterwork property:

- +1 on attack rolls (obvious, I know, but I mention it for completion)
- can be enchanted later with enhancement bonuses or special abilities
- can be targeted by effects such as the Bless Equipment feat

### Roleplaying benefits of the masterwork property:

- it marks you as a Professional; you're not just some dunce with a stick, you're a vampire hunter and it's a honed weapon thankyouverymuch

### Why you might want this kit:

Having four of these weapons at basically no cost can be extremely helpful. I know you aren't asking about the usefulness of wooden stakes generally, but here are some often-overlooked benefits.

- can be hidden on your person with Sleight of Hand
- can be used while grappled
- can be wielded by almost any party member who might need one (maybe his/her own weapons got confiscated because they couldn't be hidden!)

All of those benefits also apply to daggers, of course, but getting four of *those* masterwork would cost you more than 1,000 gold.

Comment: Another minor benefit: there are a small number of spells and abilities like Heat Metal and Magnetic Field that affect things made of metal. The stakes are unaffected and deal piercing damage, whereas most wooden weapons deal bludgeoning damage.